# Editing fail2ban apache-noscript config to add "AH10244: invalid URI path"

Tags: apache-2.4, regex, fail2ban

I have the following (default) `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-noscript.conf` configuration file:

```
[Definition]

script = /\S*(?:php(?:[45]|[.-]cgi)?|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl|\bcgi-bin/)

prefregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s (?:AH0(?:01(?:28|30)|1(?:264|071)|2811): )?(?:(?:[Ff]ile|script|[Gg]ot) )<F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$

failregex = ^(?:does not exist|not found or unable to stat): <script>\b
            ^'<script>\S*' not found or unable to stat
            ^error '[Pp]rimary script unknown(?:\\n)?'
```

I noticed the following error didn't trigger the jail:

```
 AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/%2e%2e/etc/hosts)
```

I think this should belong to the `apache-noscript` jail... from my understanding, I need to adjust both the `prefregex` and the `failregex`? I don't think `AH10244` match `(?:AH0(?:01(?:28|30)|1(?:264|071)|2811): )?`, but I don't fully understand why is `prefregex` needed at all even after reading the [official doc](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html#FILTER_FILES_(filter.d/*.conf)).

Any help to get me started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not extremely elegant but I was able to make it working...

```
[Definition]

script = /\S*(?:php(?:[45]|[.-]cgi)?|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl|\bcgi-bin/)

prefregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s ((?:(?:AH0(?:01(?:28|30)|1(?:264|071)|2811): )?(?:(?:[Ff]ile|script|[Gg]ot) ))|(?:AH10244: ))<F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$

failregex = ^(?:does not exist|not found or unable to stat): <script>\b
            ^'<script>\S*' not found or unable to stat
            ^error '[Pp]rimary script unknown(?:\\n)?'
            ^invalid URI path
```

Basically, I kept much of the original `prefregex` as-is but I added an `OR` clause with `(?:AH10244: )` to hit the `AH10244` error I'm looking for. Then, I just added an additional `failregex` at the end with `^invalid URI path`.

This is tested with Apache 2.4 exclusively and won't work with every setup. Also, to test whether it's working or not, we can use `fail2ban-regex -v` with the logfile and the configuration file:

```
fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/apache2/errors.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-noscript.conf
```